# change sql server login username

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have asp.net application that have a connection string using windows authentication.my system work in network domain.

When I try to open application connection string use this `domain\Machin Name` for login.
But I want change it to this `domain\MyUserName`,
how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass IP address of server in the Server, database name, and credentials mainly username and password, here is sample to do like this:

data source=ServerIp;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;user Id=Username;
Password=Password;

if it doesn't have a default server connection then need to change server as (serverip)(sql instance). like 192.16.3.1\SQLEXPRESS

there will have default sa username and password, if u don't know it create new user in sql mananagement studio => security => Logins

Comment: i cant use user and pass for the reason

Comment: Ok, In the case of u don't what to share your  sql credential for the security purpose then, you need to change the application logics or db connections to service, like WCF or webapi..

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new User for this problem as below:

- Create new user with Administrator privilege with same username and password.
- On SQL Server database create new user by expanding `DatabaseNode->Security->Login->Create New User` and add this new user with Windows Authentication radio button selected. This user can be only added by selected Windows Authentication it is Operating system’s User Login.

Linked: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/02/sql-server-fix-error-login-failed-for-user-username-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection/